# warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations: javax.annotation.Generated

Tags: java, netbeans, annotations, generated, annotation-processor

I'm working on a module project in NetBeans 8.2, with a GUI and everything. I'm using lots of the IDE functionality to auto-generate code for the GUI.

Every time I do a clean build of my project, I get a warning from the compiler:

```
warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations:javax.annotation.Generated
```

Browsing the *build* directory, I see that the IDE generates a class for me, *Bundle.java*, and it slaps the given annotation on top of it:

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value="org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbBundleProcessor")
```

I need this warning to go away. I tried searching the web for an annotation processor that processes this specific annotation but I had no luck. Does an annotation processor for this specific annotation exist?

If this is a "harmless warning," I need to understand why it is harmless to justify its existence in my build output.

If needed I can include in this question the argument to the `-processorpath` option that is passed to *javac* from the IDE; I didn't include it on purpose because it is very long but I can add it if necessary

#### EDIT #1:

I did a "hacky" modification to the *common.xml* file under the NetBeans installation directory to make the invocation to *javac* not include the `-processorpath` option, and doing so makes the warning dissapear. I still do not understand why that is the case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No processor claimed any of these annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69439506/no-processor-claimed-any-of-these-annotations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix for this is to remove the `@Messages` annotation from the TopComponent class that is generated by the NetBeans code generator. It is that annotation that is responsible for generating the Bundle class, as per the [NbBundle.Messages API Documentation](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.4/javadoc/org-openide-util/org/openide/util/NbBundle.Messages.html).

As soon as you remove that annotation, you might get warnings from other annotations that rely on the contents of the `@Messages` annotation (i.e. TopComponent.OpenActionRegistration), so make sure to modify the contents of those annotation as well until nothing in your code depends on that Bundle anymore.

Hopefully nothing else in your code relies on your Bundle.