# No processor claimed any of these annotations

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite

Upgraded from java 8 to java 11 and getting below warnings for annotations.Please suggest how to resolve.

```
[WARNING] No processor claimed any of these annotations: 
/org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary,
/org.springframework.data.annotation.Id,
/org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan,
/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication,
/org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties,
/org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query,
/com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude,
/javax.validation.constraints.NotNull,
/org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource,
/org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping,
/org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
```

Comment: did u tried compiling on java 11 before running it?

Comment: Yes, this is showing in compilation.

Comment: add springboot to your classpath or build project using maven. make sure you have internet connection allowing download of springboot libraries.

Comment: This doesn't look like a real problem to be. See the explanations and details mentioned in here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6421

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The javac linter has a number of warnings that are really off-the-wall, and you can't turn them off individually. This is one of them. I'd suggest using a different linter.

You can't turn off this specific warning, you can only turn off all  annotation processor warnings with the  `-processing` flag to `-Xlint`, eg.

`-Xlint:all,-serial,-processing`

in Maven:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <!-- We turn off:
                        - `serial` because we don't use Java serialization 
                          (and all it does is stupidly complain about the serialVersionUID)
                        - `processing` because it complains about every annotation
                    -->
                    <arg>-Xlint:all,-serial,-processing</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

You can see all the warnings that will be disable by searching for "warn.proc" in [compiler.properties](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/resources/compiler.properties). You can see all linter options with `javac --help-lint`.