# Why "warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations: androidx.annotation.RequiresApi"

Tags: android-studio

An app uses @RequiresApi in many places such as this one:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public synchronized  void setCallback(MediaCodec.Callback callback) {
   ...
}
```

Building the app with Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2 generates the following warning:

> warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations: androidx.annotation.RequiresApi...

Could anyone shed some light on the cause of this warning?
I see a post about how to avoid the warning. I am more interested in finding the cause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No processor claimed any of these annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69439506/no-processor-claimed-any-of-these-annotations)

Comment: As I stated in my question, I am primarily interested in finding the cause of this warning.

Comment: The causes are: 1. You use an annotation 2. You do not have an annotation processor handling that annotation (which is totally normal for many annotation types) 3. You tell the compiler to warn about such cases by using -Xlint:processing (or -Xlint:all) somewhere. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html#examples-of-using--xlint-keys

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful. I don't remember if Android Studio has had this issue all along or started to have it only recently. Do you happen to know this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as I do not use Android Studio.

Comment: Since I was asking why, not a solution, I feel your comment is a better answer though a good solution without turning off the warning would be good. Could you turn your comment into an answer? You could refer to the other answer in your answer.